# How to redirect to homepage when will enter filename which is not availble in the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to redirect to the home page when a user enters a filename in the url which is not available in the project.

This is my code in Global.asax.cs:

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
   Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
   Server.ClearError();
   Response.Redirect("/Home/GuestSearch");
 }
```

It is working on a local machine i.e. when `http://localhost:54683/a` is entered then a user is redirecting to the home page, but it is not working when deployed - it is showing runtime error.

Comment: Is your IIS application setup correctly for MVC? Do other Actions in your application operate as expected?

Comment: It sounds like a release build configuration issue.  try ``temporarily`` turning off <compilation debug=”true”/> in web.config.  This could prove it one way or another

Comment: i have <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" /> in web.config file

Comment: @kumarswamy ...Yes he said to turn OFF that option, so change it to debug="false" and see what happens

Comment: it is working fine but any problem if we make debug to false